# PHP PDO check for mysql error

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have this problem that drives me crazy. All i want is just check a query for an error, if so display error, otherwise run the query.

I have the following almost (since it runs the insert query twice) working

```
[..]

$dbdata = new mySQLAccessData();
$db = new PDO($dbdata->hostname,$dbdata->username,$dbdata->password);
$defaults = new Defaults();

[..]

if(!$db->exec($sql)){
    echo($defaults->throwError('MySql error',implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
}else{
    $db->exec($sql);
    $defaults->writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'add');
}
```

I tried numerous things (amongst others the `try(){}catch(){}` method) but nothing worked except for the code above. It shows the error the way i want, and only when an error occurs, but runs the `exec()` twice...

Can someone bail me out?

Comment: Read here http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: Why not assign the result of `$db->exec($sql)` into a variable. `$result = $db->exec($sql);`. And then use the `$result` value in the `if($result)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to execute the query again in the `else` part? Usually you just try to run the query and if errors happen, react on them.

```
[..]

$dbdata = new mySQLAccessData();
$db = new PDO($dbdata->hostname,$dbdata->username,$dbdata->password);
$defaults = new Defaults();

[..]

if(!$db->exec($sql)){
    echo($defaults->throwError('MySql error',implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
}else{
    $defaults->writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'add');
}
```

As far as I know, there is no option to "test" a query before actually executing it.

Comment: Ah, didn't know the query would run inside the <code>if()</code> part. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Maurice The query runs as soon as you trigger the `exec()` method. No matter in which context you do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see an exception thrown when an error occurs, just [set the PDO error-mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) (see also: [Connections and Connection management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)):

```
$db = new PDO($dbdata->hostname,$dbdata->username,$dbdata->password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This for example will make your code throw exceptions automatically. Probably exactly what you're looking for.

The actual issue with your code is doing `exec` twice. You don't need to:

```
$success = $db->exec($sql);

if (!$success) {
    echo $defaults->throwError('MySql error', implode(":", $db->errorInfo()));
} else {
    # do not exec *again* here.
    $defaults->writeLog($table, $db->lastInsertId(), 'add');
}
```